# How to read images from a remote sftp file server

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, sftp

So I'm using CodeIgniter PHP Framework for a website. We have a few servers, a live, a dev, and a file server. We've successfully been able to upload files to our dev server, and then secure copy them to our file server for storage. Our problem now is a way to read/display the images on our dev website from the file server. Our file server uses sftp for it's security. We've been looking into different ways to just pass back an image object from the file server, but not actually the actual file. Any suggestions on how to do this? Thanks.

CodeIgniter PHP Framework
Linux Servers
SFTP on the file server

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have not dealed with sftp so much but at lest I will try to give you some steps to begin.

1. You need install some apache/php module like [ssh2](http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php) and enable it with `extension=php_ssh2.dll`.
2. You could make your own sftp library, like this:

   class Sftp{

   ```
   protected $connection;

   public function __construct($params)
       {

       }

       public function connect()
       {
       $server = "you-server.com";
       $port = "1234";
       $username = "admin";
       $password = "blabla";

       //connect
       $ssh2 = ssh2_connect($server, $port);

       if(ssh2_auth_password($ssh2, $username, $password))
       {
           //sftp session
           $this->connection = ssh2_sftp($resConnection);
       }
       else
       {
           echo "Unable to connect to server";
       }
       }

   public function download($image_name)
   {
       $image = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$this->connection}/path/to/{$image_name}", 'r');
       fclose($image);
   }

   }
   ```

And then try to use it like:
        $this->sftp->connect();
        $image = $this->sftp->download('image-name');

Answer (score 0):

I found this Codeigniter library on Github. I haven't used it yet but it seems like you need to do several steps before you could use load the library using Codeigniter. Otherwise this looks promising.

https://github.com/ipolar/CodeIgniter-sFTP-Library